# How to have 2 layers in opengl on android?

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, transparency

I have one layer that is animated with 1 texture

I have one layer with a transparent image that is static (non-animated)

How can I layer the transparent image on top of the moving background so that both show?

This must occur within opengl as I am using the LiveWallPaperService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw two textured quads on top of each other with depth testing disabled and with a blend mode of your choice.

Relevant OpenGL procedures:

- glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
- glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
- glEnable(GL_BLEND_MODE);
- glBlendFunc(…, …), see the documentation for values. You probably want (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) for regular pictures or (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) for premultiplied alpha. I recommend doing later.